# Outlook not showing options to download media

Tags: outlook, office365, outlook-2010, office365-apps

In incoming mail of outlook, Images are not downloading automatically. I have tried to download it automatically through ***File > Options > Trust Center >  Trust Center Settings***. I have unchecked all things from there. But there is no success.

I had a "**Click here to download media**" option below the sender's profile icon. But somehow, I can't see that option also. I am not able to download media automatically.

[image]

I have also tried to move the sender to the safe sender list through junk mail settings. The sender is now on the safe sender list. But still, I am not able to download media automatically.

Is there any other way to download it automatically/manually?

Answer (score 0):

If HTML references external images, the message must be stamped with a special property that cannot be transmitted and can only be set locally, either by the end user or programmatically (see [PidTagBlockStatus](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/openspecs/exchange_server_protocols/ms-oxomsg/be7b4a94-c3d3-426a-8e20-c57ced913e8d)).

Note that you cannot set `PidTagBlockStatus` property using OOM - it always truncates date/time values to the nearest minute and you will need the exact value of the `PidTagMessageDeliveryTime` MAPI property .

If using [Redemption](http://www.dimastr.com/redemption) (I am its author) is an option, you can set set `PidTagBlockStatus` property using [RDOMail](http://www.dimastr.com/redemption/RDOMail.htm).`DownloadPictures` property.